# I can hear but others cannot hear me in Skype

Tags: sound, skype, microphone, volume-control

I instilled Skype in Ubuntu 14.04 but I have the problem that the people who I am talking with  cannot hear me. What should I do to fix that?

(The people I'm trying to talk to are using Skype on Windows.)

Comment: Have you checked your microphone settings, (may be it is muted).

Answer (score 1):

The usual situation is that the various volume levels are set wrong. If you right-click on the speaker icon you'll see "Sound Settings". If you click the "Input" tab you'll see your input volume settings. Make sure it's not muted and is at a reasonable level.